# Modal pop up keeps dissapearing after opened. (How do I find conflicting scripts?)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, content-management-system, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement a bootstrap modal on a CTA on the hero image. It kinda works, it pops up but then dissapears immediately.

I'm aware that it might be because I have two versions of the same library running BUT since it's a CMS I am not sure how to target these scripts or edit them out because I'm afraid I might crash the whole bloody thing.

It's just a simple Bootstrap modal.

```js
//THESE ARE ALL THE SCRIPTS RUNNING ON THE PAGE

<head id="Head1">
<meta charset="utf-8" /><link rel="icon" href="/costar.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dtc-v6t.com/js/45363.js">
  
</script>
<noscript><img src="http://www.dtc-v6t.com/45363.png" style="display:none;" /></noscript>
</script><script type="text/javascript">$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav li:nth-child(5)").text("Market Your Space");
});
</script><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?d=R_u6bpYKrV_wf3yBwIyPzlvxi8v-72YlfkC9vnieL_7HEsHSRUO_Bkhy5iF20mzVFFRNI2kS-9WuklIISZfKKGH6aLFpcG5bN_q8tlKIBUxWd9LaMjguwIEvJ016T4rGSLUc3g2&amp;t=636160552680000000&amp;compress=0&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bTelerik.Sitefinity.Resources%2c+Version%3d8.2.5900.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3db28c218413bdf563%3aen-GB%3a6a9f3ba9-0b01-4890-9b6c-b4a98b0257b5%3a83fa35c7%3a7a90d6a" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!--CUSTOM SCRIPT TO ADD BUTTON-->
<script>
$(function() {
    var html = '<button id="watchVideoBtn" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">Watch video</button>';

$(".heroimage-calltoaction").replaceWith(html)
});




$(function() {
    $("ul.nav li:nth-child(5)").text("Market Your Space");
});
$(function() {
    $("ul.nav li#productLink").insertAfter($("ul.nav li:nth-child(4)"));
});
</script>
<!--CUSTOM SCRIPT TO ADD BUTTON-->


<link href="/Sitefinity/Public/ResponsiveDesign/layout_transformations.css?unique_key=6362c0c5-018f-4bc2-8741-ca2add2e1e5a" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/CoStarUK/App_Themes/CoStarUK/global/Reset.css?v=635495676080000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/CoStarUK/App_Themes/CoStarUK/global/Layout.css?v=635495676080000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/CoStarUK/App_Themes/CoStarUK/global/video-js.css?v=635495676080000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Sitefinity/WebsiteTemplates/CoStarUK/App_Themes/CoStarUK/global/costaruk.css?v=635495676080000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/costar.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/demoModal.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/video-js/video.js"></script>
 <script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "/Scripts/video-js/video-js.swf"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the modal.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance xox

Comment: Please add the include of the librarys.

Comment: @DomeTune I have added all the scripts used on the page now, thanks.

Comment: @DaryinHigginson you have a `</script>`-tag to much after your `</noscript>`-tag, is it only wrong here or in your code as well ?

Comment: @DomeTune I have added all the scripts that are present globally. I wouldn't even know how to target them because it's on a massive corporate website Content Management system. I wouldn't want to change anything either (-_-')

Comment: @DomeTune Yeah that is how I found it haha

Comment: Can you remove this `</script>`?

Comment: @DomeTune Very strange but it doesn't seem to be there in the source code..How does it get there?

Comment: **<script type="text/javascript">**

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dtc-v6t.com/js/45363.js">  
</script>
<noscript><img src="http://www.dtc-v6t.com/45363.png" style="display:none;" /></noscript>
</script><script type="text/javascript">$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav li:nth-child(5)").text("Market Your Space");
});

**</script>** 

Remove scripts  tags one mark as bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the widgets on your page (or on the corresponding Page Template) - there is probably one or more Javascript widgets there. 
In Sitefinity, the javascript widget adds the  tag automatically, but often times the content editors add  tag as well, resulting in double script tags rendered on the page.

So you want to make sure all javascript widgets on the page do NOT have a script tag in their body.

Comment: Thank you @Veselin. Problem is I honestly can't find where this script is coming from...Is there any way to remove it WITH script? I can see it in the console, but just don't know where it's coming from.